# Parsec's satisfy equivalent in uu-parsinglib

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, uu-parsinglib

I am looking for a `satisfy` function like the one Parsec has. Something like:

```
--The parser satisfy f succeeds for any character for which the supplied
--function f returns True.
--Returns the character that is actually parsed.
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
```

The only thing I have found is [pSatisfy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib-2.8.1.1/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-UU-BasicInstances.html#v:pSatisfy), which requires an `Insertion` as argument. I don't understand why this is necessary... I just want the parser to fail in case the predicate is not satisfied!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to hack up a `satisfy` function which meeted my needs. However, uu-parsinglib is an error correcting parser and will throw an exception in case you don't provide a correcting alternative.

This means you should use the normal `pSatisfy` function and provide an `Insertion` element. If you are not sure about what the cost should be you can use 5, as seen in the implementations of other parsers like `pSymbol`.